# Vue3 | TypeScript. Как задать тип для props, если на входе массив объектов?

Tags: typescript, vue3

Есть массив объектов, который будет воходящим параметром в vue-компоненте:

```
const items = reactive([
  { type: 'Java Script', is_main: true },
  { type: 'Python', is_main: false },
  { type: 'Go', is_main: false },
  { type: 'PHP', is_main: false },
]);
```

Внутри компонета:

```
const props = defineProps<Props>();
interface Props {
    items: string[]; <--
}
```

При монтировании я хочу найти объект с определенным условием:

[image: picture]

Но TS судя по-всему string[] воспринимает буквально как набор строк, а не объектов:

```
any
Property 'is_main' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

Как правильно задать тип для props, если на входе массив объектов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и задайте:

```
interface Props {
  items: {
    type: string;
    is_main: boolean;
  }[];
}

defineProps<Props>()
```

Comment: Спасибо. А есть какая-то возможность задать что-то вроде items: string[{}] - на случай, если неизвестны названия  ключей?

Comment: @overus непонятно. Каких ключей? У вас объекты в массиве `items` имеют строго определенную структуру. О каких ключах речь?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что вместо `type` и `is_main` может быть что угодно, тогда используйте либо встроенный дженерик `Record<string, string>`, либо `{[p: string]: string}`